# Django Multiple Generic Foreign Keys - How to Structure DRF Serializer

Tags: python, django, generics, django-rest-framework

I have read the documentation about Content Type for Django, but I cannot seem to correctly think of a way to apply it to my situation. The common 'Tag' example is a little too simplistic.

My situation: I have a Model called Docket. It has several fields which hold various simplistic values. However, it also needs to have a destination and a source. In my app, destinations and sources can both be either a Facility Object or a TransFrontier Object.

So for example, you could have a Docket which has a Facility as it's source and a TransFrontier as its destination.

You could also have a Docket with a TransFrontier as its source and a Faclity as its destination.

Additionally, users will not be creating new Facility or TransFrontier objects when they create a new docket. These will existing Facility or TF objects we already have in the database.

So to do this I initially thought of ContentType and Generic Foreign Key. I came up with this model:

```
class Docket(BaseDocket):

    # Fields
    dest_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    destination = GenericForeignKey("dest_c_type", "dest_id")
    source_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    source = GenericForeignKey("source_c_type", "source_id")

    # limit dest & source to facility and transfrontier
    limit = models.Q(app_label='facilities', model='facility') | models.Q(app_label='permitting', model='transfrontier')

    # Relationship Fields
    dest_c_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name="dest_c_type", limit_choices_to=limit)
    source_c_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name="source_c_type", limit_choices_to=limit)

class TransFrontier(models.Model):
    # fields for TF ...

class Facility(models.Model):
    # fields for Facility ...
```

Is this the correct structure for this?

Does anyone know how I would make a DRF serializer for this kind of relationship? I'm unsure of how to POST data to it mostly.

Comment: Just a thought, can you drop the GenericForeignKeys and instead use standard ForeignKeys with a third field which specifies direction? Might simplify your model a bit.

Comment: Not really. As it's also possible to have a Facility to Facility docket... I did think of having Facility and TransFrontier extend a common Base model, however it then would generate huge SQL overheads...